Dropping Voltage from 1.8 to 1.2 volts
I have a circuit that does not work on Lithium-ion Lithium AA batteries. I wanted to use these to extend the life of my circuit which is electromagnetic pendulum. The voltage of these (e.g. Energizer Ultimate Lithium AA) are 1.8 volts and it's too high for my circuit to work properly.
How can I drop 1.8 volts to 1.2 volts without affecting the current supplied by the batteries? I have two AA batteries ran in parallel. Would dropping the voltage from 1.8 to 1.2 extend the battery life and be more efficient than using 1.2 volt batteries?

The question originally said the batteries were Lithium-ion AA but I meant Lithium, so that is corrected above. However an answer already used the original false information from the question, so I'm making it clear that this correction to the question occurred after that answer was written.

Add a diode in series with the output.

I've tried a couple different schottky diodes but I am also loosing current after the diode

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@WylieWisnewski - Hi, Just to clarify, you referred to "lithium ion aa batteries". Did you really mean Lithium-ion? My experience of those is that the built-in buck regulator outputs a steady 1.5V not 1.8V. Perhaps you misspoke and meant the Lithium AA batteries (cells) which are actually an Li-FeS2 chemistry (not Li-ion) e.g. the Energizer Ultimate Lithium? Its datasheet shows the no- or low-load voltage can be up to around 1.8V. Is that what you meant?

Yes, sorry. I meant Lithium aa batteries. I tested the energizer ultimate lithium aa batteries and the voltage was to high for the circuit to work. The sweet spot seems to be around 1.2 volts. I can get my pendulum to swing for around 2 months with the NiMH rechargeable batteries with 2 batteries in parallel.  I am trying to extend the swing time which is why I was trying the lithium aa.

@SamGibson: Thank you for your edit which clarified OP's actual question.

@DavideAndrea - Thanks, as I'm just about to comment to the OP, the correction seems important. So the least bad option seems to be to allow the edit, but to make it clear that it was made after your answer.

@WylieWisnewski - Thanks for explaining. Unfortunately an answer used that original false information from the question and it now appears partially wrong, because of that original mistake in the question. || Correcting that error in the question is important, to prevent more people addressing the Li-ion AA batteries, which isn't applicable here. But that correction partially invalidates an answer, which should be avoided where possible. || Therefore I have done the least bad thing and allowed the correction to the question, but made it clear that happened after that answer was written.

Just an FYI to readers who are unfamiliar with the Lithium AA batteries - there is a relevant Q&A here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/276540/what-is-the-truth-about-1-5-v-lithium-cells

”but I am also loosing current after the diode” Physically impossible for a two terminal device. The current going in is equal to the current going out as per KCL.

You would use a buck converter. Not an LM337: that is a linear regulator and is not efficient.
But, if I may, let me have you step back and look at the big picture. ~~A 1.8 V Li-ion AA battery is actually a 3.6 V Li-ion cell plus a DC-DC converter. Which is why its charge doesn't last long. So, you are already staring from an inefficient solution and you're making it even less efficient.~~
Instead, use NiMH cells:

They are already 1.2 V
They have a low self-discharge so they last a long time at a low current draw
100 % of their volume is energy storage (no volume is used in electronics).

EDIT
I see your edit: "The question originally said the batteries were Lithium-ion AA but I meant Lithium". In that case, please disregard the top half of my answer, which was based on your incorrect information.

Okay. Thanks for your reply and advise.  Initially I was thinking I could get my pendulum to swing longer if I went will a lithium ion battery such as the energizer ultimate lithium. So any NiMH rechargeable battery is what you would recommend? Do you have any suggestions for high capacity long lasting  NiMH batteries?

I doubt that you'd find any NiMH cell that has a significantly higher capacity than any other NiMH cell.

" a lithium ion battery such as the energizer ultimate lithium". The energizer ultimate lithium is not a Li-ion cell. It is a primary (non-rechargeable) cell that adds a bit of Lithium to improve performance. Your confusion on that matter led me astray. Please ignore the first half of my answer.

Hello again. I did find a buck converter.  It converts 2.5+ volts to 1.2 volts. My question now is what is the most efficient way to wire up two aa battery packs with 2 batteries per pack? Would lithium batteries increase efficiency to increase run time?

"My question now is ..." Please start a new submission and ask that question.

A forward biased diode will drop about 0.6 or 0.7 volts without costing you significant current or battery life. Many, many diode parts will meet your requirement; one example is about $0.1 in quantity: 1N4148TR DIODE GEN PURP 100V 200MA DO35. The property you're looking for is "Voltage forward" (Vf) and the one I chose for you is about 0.7V.
I don't know your skill level, and my intent is not to insult. A procedure assuming that you're least skilled:

place the diode in series with your load, and if it works at all, your design is done.
If it doesn't work, swap the diode around and try again.
Measure the voltage across your load and you should expect about 1.2V if your battery is 1.8V

Cheers!

Thanks for your advice.  I've tried a couple diodes but probably didn't have the right ones. If I use the lithium ion batteries and the diode how does that affect the battery life? Would be be more efficient to do this or use 1.2 v batteries?

Diode voltage drop will depend on current and temperature. For a 1N4148 simulated
at 27 C for a range of 100 uA to 160 mA I get 480 mV to 900 mV, which is roughly what I see in several datasheets. Temperature will affect it as well, I get 100 mV difference from 0 to 50 degrees C @ 1 mA.

A series diode will reduce the voltage across the load, which will decrease the load current somewhat.  However, it is not a very efficient down-converter.  At your low voltages, nothing is.
For voltage reduction plus more efficient load sharing between two batteries, I'd go with standard AA cells and Shottkey diodes, one per battery.  If the two batteries are not at the same voltage, the diodes will prevent reverse currents.  If they are at nearly the same voltage, the diodes form a "droop-share" circuit that has both batteries contributing to the load, again without reverse currents.
An alternative is changing to NiMH batteries. These have a nominal cell voltage of 1.2 V. Because no two batteries have exactly the same cell voltage, and do not discharge at exactly the same rate, connecting two of them in direct parallel will cause one battery to appear as a load on the other battery.  You will get more operating time than with a single cell, but not twice.  Can you change to a single, larger cell, such as a C?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%E2%80%93metal_hydride_battery
ak

Thanks for your reply. I'd like to stick with the aa because of popularity and I can find panel mounts boxes for aa that I convert to parallel.  My plan is to use two battery backs, each with 2 NiMH aa batteries ran in parallel to the circuit to increase run time of the pendulum. Do I need any diodes with this setup or is there anything else you'd suggest?

With the batteries in parallel, a Shottkey diode will drop the working voltage down below 1 V.
